# Split a string into an array and set the delimiter as the key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string of data as such.

```
$str = "abc/text text def/long amount of text ghi/some text"
```

I have an array of my delimiters

```
$arr = array('abc/', 'def/', 'ghi/', 'jkl/');
```

What can I do to get this output?

```
Array
(
   [abc/] => text text
   [def/] => long amount of text
   [ghi/] => some text
)
```

Also note that all the values in $arr may not always appear in $str.  I just noticed this to be a problem after using the code from @rohitcopyright below.

Comment: can you give us an exact example of the input?

Comment: Where are your values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` instead

```
$text = "abc/text text def/long amount of text ghi/some text";
$output = preg_split( "/(abc\/|def\/|ghi)/", $text);
var_dump($output);
```

**Output:**

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(10) "text text "
    [2]=>
    string(20) "long amount of text "
    [3]=>
    string(10) "/some text"
}
```

**Update:** (remove empty item and re-index)

```
$output = array_values(array_filter(preg_split( "/(abc\/|def\/|ghi)/", $text)));
var_dump($output);
```

**output:**

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "text text "
    [1]=>
    string(20) "long amount of text "
    [2]=>
    string(10) "/some text"
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QQa6My)

**Update : (26th sep, 2013)**

```
$str = "abc/text text def/long amount of text ghi/some text";
$array = preg_split( "/([a-z]{3}\/)/", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$odd = $even = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
    if ($k % 2 == 0) $odd[] = $v;
    else $even[] = $v;
}
$output = array_combine($odd, $even);

print_r($output);
```

**Output:**

```
Array (
    [abc/] => text text 
    [def/] => long amount of text 
    [ghi/] => some text 
)
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NUHAIP)

**Update :  (26th sep, 2013)**

You may try this as well (only change following line to achieve the result that you mentioned in comment)

```
$array = preg_split( "/([a-zA-Z]{1,4}\/)/", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/10Nj92)

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  I want the abc/, def/ and ghi/ to end up as my index (key) and not have the [0], [1], etc...

Comment: @davipilot, it was not clear to me before, sorry for that, hope you want this (last update).

Comment: @davipilot, please let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Almost there.  I apologize as I am learning how to use this site for help as well.  Okay, so all the text that will be in $str will be in ALL CAPS.  I noticed that was an issue so I changed [a-z] to [A-Z].  Now I just get "Array" returned with no values.  The other part I should mention is that the number of characters prior to the "/" will not always be 3.  It could be 1, 2, 3 or 4 characters, but never more than 4.  That should cover more of the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this you will get the exact output as you want.


$con='abc/text text def/long amount of text ghi/some text';
$newCon = explode('/', $con);
array_shift($newCon);
$arr = array('abc/', 'def/', 'ghi/');
foreach($newCon as $key=>$val){
       $newArrStr = str_replace("/", "", $arr[$key+1]);
       $newVal = str_replace($newArrStr, "", $newCon[$key]);
    $newArray[$arr[$key]] = $newVal; 
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: This is the closest answer I tested.  I get the following output.  'Array ([0]=>abc/[1]=>def/[2]=>ghi/[abc/]=>text text [def/]=>long amount of text [ghi/]=>some text)'What can I do to only have the following return:  'Array ([abc/]=>text text [def/]=>long amount of text [ghi/]=>some text)'

Comment: if you add another value to the $arr - array such as jkl/ which doesn't show up in the $con string, I noticed this messes things up.  What can I do about that?

Comment: It is working perfectly...Sure you are missing something in your code...just copy this code and run it ..you will get the exact output.