# Formatting Data from ID Barcode Scanner

Tags: php, string, parsing, formatting, keyup

I have data coming in from a ID scanner that looks like this:

```
@
ANSI 636014040002DL00410276ZC03170033DLDCACDCBNONEDCDNONEDBA02102016DCSBENITEZDACMELISSADADCECILDBD08f02015DBB02101990DBC2DAYBRNDAU064 INDAG2341 LINRTLN AVEDAICHfINODAJCADAK934100000  DAQD8dd1412DCF01/03/201161111/DDFD/16DCGUSADDEUDDFUDDGUDAW150DAZBRNDCK15232D84914120401DDB04162010DDD0
ZCZCAZCBZCCBRNZCDBRNZCEZCF
```

I need to extract data from this string of text with a key I have

EXA: for key "DCS" it would be the last name. So from the string it would output "BENITEZ"

I am not sure what the best way would be to parse this string and get all the values I need. The problem i'm having is that the keyup triggered sends the text in one big chunk instead of sending each line separately.

Thanks In Advance!

Here are some scans that are causing issues.

```
@
ANSI 636040080002DL00443261ZU03020011DLDAQ212306482DCSREZADDENDACGILBERTDDFNDADCHRISTIANDDGNDCADDCBADCDNONEDBD04142017DBB08201994DBA08202019DBC1DAU066 inDAYBRODAG123 SUNRISE CTDAIST GEORGEDAJUTDAK847700000  DCF32784241DCGUSADAW135DAZBRODCK216206482UT1TT

@
ANSI 636014040002DL00410280ZC03210033DLDCACDCBNONEDCDNONEDBA06202020DCSJIMENEZDACERIKDADALISBAHANDBD05062016DBB06201991DBC1DAYBLKDAU067 INDAG12345 MARQUETTE LNDAIPOMONADAJCADAK917660000  DAQE1312327DCF05/06/201661227/CCFD/20DCGUSADDEUDDFUDDGUDAW155DAZBR


@ANSI6360450102DL00390234ZW02730027DLDAAKHA,HOANG,TUDAG16130 BORDER AVE
WDAILYNNWOODDAJWADAK98037DAQKHAA**HT392JGDARDASDATDBA20100407DBB19610407DBC1DBD2005
0322DAU507DAW160DAYBRODAL16130 BORDER AVE
WDANLYNNWOODDAOWADAP98037ZWZWA050812E1551ZWBZWC32 

@
ANSI 636009030202DL00410203ZN02440063DLDBA12222020DCSZALDIIVARDCTMICHAEL GEORGEDBD08242016DBB11221985DBC1DAYBRODAU068 inDAG1234 FRINTAGE RD 2116DAILAS VEGASDAJNMDAK877010000  DAQ501231283DCFunavailDCK50960128302DCGUSADCHNONE
ZNZNAZNB5'08"ZNC175ZND9999999

@ - ANSI 636000030001DL00310440DLDCANONE DCB158X9 DCDS
DBA08142017 DCSMAURY DCTJUSTIN,WILLIAM
DBD08142009 DBB07151958 DBC1 DAYBRO DAU075 in DAG123 FIRST STREET
DAISTAUNTON DAJVA DAK244010000 DAQT16123185
DCF061234567 DCGUSA DCHS DDC00000000 DDB12102008 DDD
```

Comment: So does `DCS` AND `DAC` mark the start and ending?

Comment: No, DAC would be first name. If I can somehow grab the text between 2 keys then I can work with that.

Comment: Melissa is the firstname, no? Maybe `preg_split` on `D[A-Z]{2}`.. This assumes your inputs would never have a three letter word like `DAD` or even a word with `D--` anywhere in it. https://3v4l.org/nLHaQ

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! I'm not sure if i'll run into that issue. This is going to be used to scan driver's licenses.

Comment: Given names such as `Candice`, `Dave`, `Dan`, etc. would all cause false matches. It would be better if you had a set list of known delimiters.

Comment: I have a list of all the delimiters such as DCS for last name, DAC for first name, etc. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, use those in the the regex with an alteration. Then you can do something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996220/split-a-string-into-an-array-and-set-the-delimiter-as-the-key, and extract the values you need.

Comment: Thank You Chris!! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by using chris85's suggested method with `preg_replace`

```
$scan = "@
ANSI 636014040002DL00410276ZC03170033DLDCACDCBNONEDCDNONEDBA02102016DCSBENITEZDACMELISSADADCECILDBD08f02015DBB02101990DBC2DAYBRNDAU064 INDAG2341 LINRTLN AVEDAICHfINODAJCADAK934100000  DAQD8dd1412DCF01/03/201161111/DDFD/16DCGUSADDEUDDFUDDGUDAW150DAZBRNDCK15232D84914120401DDB04162010DDD0
ZCZCAZCBZCCBRNZCDBRNZCEZCF";

$output = preg_split( "/(DBA|DCS|DAC|DAD|DBD|DBB|DBC|DAY|DAU|DAG|DAI|DAJ|DAK|DAQ|DCF|DCG|DDE|DDF|DDG|DAW|DAZ|DCK|DDB|DDD|ZCZ|ZCB|ZCC|ZCD|ZCE|ZCF)/", $scan);
```

Answer (score 0):

While your piped regex expression may yield your intended result.  I have a concerns and a couple of new suggested patterns.

First, the barcode scanner is delivering the data without an unreliable set of delimiters.  I mean, these value "prefixes/labels" are not in alphabetical order and they may result in mismatches.  Consider a driver with the name "DAISY DAWSON HOLIDAY".  All three names have delimiters in them.  Even if these delimiters were in a strict, predictable order, some values would still monkey wrench the system.

Anyhow, I'm going to assume the data is beyond your control and try to make lemonade from the lemon...

Your piped pattern is desperately yearning for optimization.  After adding a couple of "missing" delimiters, I've condensed the pattern using character classes and ordered the alternatives from longest to shortest and in alphabetical order.  My adjustments improve the pattern's: Accuracy, Efficiency, Brevity, and Readability.

This is your pattern:

`/(DBA|DCS|DAC|DAD|DBD|DBB|DBC|DAY|DAU|DAG|DAI|DAJ|DAK|DAQ|DCF|DCG|DDE|DDF|DDG|DAW|DAZ|DCK|DDB|DDD|ZCZ|ZCB|ZCC|ZCD|ZCE|ZCF)/`

It makes 31 matches after taking a whopping 7913 steps.

---

This is my pattern:

`/DA[CDGIJKQUWYZ]|DB[ABCD]|DC[BDFGKS]|DD[BDEFG]|ZC[BCDEFZ]|DL|ZC/`

It makes 36 matches, **1759 steps**!

---

If the delimiters are in a specific order, you can write up a very literal pattern like this:

`/@\s*ANSI\s*(\S*?)DL(\S*?)ZC(\S*?)DL(\S*?)DCB(\S*?)DCD(\S*?)DBA(\S*?)DCS(\S*?)DAC(\S*?)DAD(\S*?)DBD(\S*?)DBB(\S*?)DBC(\S*?)DAY(\S*?)DAU(.*?)DAG(.*?)DAI(\S*?)DAJ(\S*?)DAK(.*?)DAQ(\S*?)DCF(\S*?)DDF(\S*?)DCG(\S*?)DDE(\S*?)DDF(\S*?)DDG(\S*?)DAW(\S*?)DAZ(\S*?)DCK(\S*?)DDB(\S*?)DDD(.*?)ZCZ(\S*?)ZCB(\S*?)ZCC(\S*?)ZCD(\S*?)ZCE(\S*?)ZCF(\s*?)/`

It's not short or pretty, but it does match 36 substrings in **635 steps**. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zwIvi3/1)

Comment: I am still having some issues with this. I noticed that sometimes the scan's delimiters are not in the same order. Is there a way to create an array of the delimiter as the key? EXA: `[DCS] => BENITEZ`

Comment: @626 This is a tricky endeavor as I previously mentioned because of the possibility of "overmatching" (find substrings that are false positive matches).  Please include 3 differing sample inputs and your expected result for each.

Comment: Only after you provide some more sample data to compare against, can we possibly identify and leverage points in the string that are stable/static/reliable to work off of.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the question with some sample data.

Comment: @626 How does this grab you? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/500ac7db9545cfc7ecd2f6e85cf2d282987a2376  If you provide any future personal details, let's be sure to protect the innocent and modify the actual details.  Please test my code on your actual data as much as you can and let me know if there are any outliers.  If this is what you want, let me know so I can update my answer, and so this page can get closer to a formalized resolution.  [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s5vm8s/1) -- I added a few more characters to the pattern.

Comment: @626 Extended pattern and added some translations: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40ae68ba2b993352c63049a773ef7c122b5100a7

Comment: @mickmacusa thanks, i'll take a look at this! FYI, all the important info was changed before I provided the sample data on this question :)